# How to copy only new files from one folder to another AND only those that are added before 5 minutes only?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I would like to copy files from one drive to another, but I only want to copy source files that are newer than the destination file. BUT, I also want to only copy source files that have been changed in last 5 minutes.

I have created one file with .bat extension and used this command :

```
xcopy "C:\Users\Pictures\Newfolder"  "C:\Users\Pictures\Newfolder2\" /d:03/29/2019
```

But this command is for date.

Comment: DateTime comparisons are much easier done in PowerShell, so I suggest to use that. `Get-ChildItem -File |Where {$_.LastWriteTime -gt [datetime]::now.AddMinutes(-5)}`

Answer (score 1):

This PowerShell script:

```
(Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\Pictures\Newfolder' |
    Where {!($_.PSIsContainer) -and
           ($_.LastWriteTime -gt [datetime]::now.AddMinutes(-5)) -and 
           (!(Test-Path (Join-Path 'C:\Users\Pictures\Newfolder2' $_.Name)))}).FullName"
```

wrapped in a batch file:

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\03\29\SU_1419009.cmd
@Echo off
Set "Src=C:\Users\Pictures\Newfolder"  
Set "Dst=C:\Users\Pictures\Newfolder2"

For /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in (`
    powershell -NoP -C "(Get-ChildItem '%Src%'|Where {!($_.PSIsContainer) -and ($_.LastWriteTime -gt [datetime]::now.AddMinutes(-5)) -and (!(Test-Path (Join-Path '%Dst%' $_.Name)))}).FullName"
`) Do (
echo Copy "%%A" "%Dst%\"
     Copy "%%A" "%Dst%\"
)
```

As is this will copy only files created/changed in the last 5 minutes, if I got that wrong,
and you mean files older than 5 minutes change the `-gt` to `-lt`.

Comment: I am executing it in file with extension .bat but its giving error of cannot find parameter name File. can u plz explain process to execute it tried with .ps1 file also

Comment: Can I do this using PHP? I am using this code for getting filemname : $filename="C:/Users/Pictures/Newfolder/Statement of Work.pdf";

if (time()-filemtime($filename) > 2 * 3600) {
  echo  "file older than 2 hours";
} else {
  echo "file younger than 2 hours";
}

Comment: The File parameter requires a more recent version of [powershell v3+](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-3.0). I'll change the script. **Done**